# Delegate function can't parse new elements.

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have problem with delegate function.

```
$(function(){
        var current, toggleBoxes = $(".togglebox").hide();

        $("table").delegate(".fname", "focus", function() {
            current = $(this).next(".togglebox");
            toggleBoxes.not(current).slideUp('fast');
            current.slideDown("fast");
        });
});
```

This works, but when I add (append) a new element to the DOM structure, and when I clicked on the new added field input, div is shown, but do not want to hide.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: If using jQuery 1.7 or above, try replacing delegate() with on(), also, the problem is probably that your toggleBoxes variable does not contain the new elements.

Comment: You have to re-select your `.togglebox`'s, the object does not get updated as you add element.

Comment: Im using jquery 1.5, how to reselect togglebox

Comment: Use some sort of callback after you have appended your new elements, and then run the variable again, 'toggleBoxes = $(".togglebox");' to get the new elements in to your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Like @adeneo said in the comment above, if you are using jquery 1.7 or above use `on()` and hide your toggleboxes. You can use css to hide all of them:

http://jsfiddle.net/CfaM5/2/

And, change a line in your delegate function from this:

```
toggleBoxes.not(current).slideUp('fast');
```

to this:

```
$(".togglebox").not(current).slideUp('fast');
```

Comment: @PiotrPo Great. I update the fiddle link because you can cut the code down a little more.

Comment: @PiotrPo Since you are new to SO, just a reminder, please accept the answer that solves your question.